# #ZoomCharts, drill down donut

Tags: zoomcharts

In your drill down donut, if I drill down to sub-level item, the items with zero-values are filtered out.

Is it possible to keep the zero-values item in filter content ?
Because I have to compare the Year-to-day value of all items with the last year-to-day value

Thanks & Regards,
Power

Answer (score 0):

You should set the setting `filters.allowZeroValues` to true like here:

http://jsfiddle.net/e7pajsdv/